# Distinct Count over row

Tags: excel

How can I count distinct text values over a row, for example:
[image]
I tried =SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIF(A2:E2,A2:E2)), but it is not showing the correct value because countif does not work along horizontal range.
The output will be:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

I assume you don't have access to the `UNIQUE` function.

The failure of your current formula has nothing to do with your statement that `COUNTIF` "*does not work along horizontal range*", which is simply not true. It needs only to be adjusted to account for blanks (or null strings), viz:

`=SUMPRODUCT(N(A2:E2<>""),1/COUNTIFS(A2:E2,A2:E2&""))`

Over small ranges, that construction is fine, though it becomes very inefficient over larger ranges. Although longer in length, a `FREQUENCY`/`MATCH` set-up would then be preferable:

`=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(A2:E2<>"",MATCH(A2:E2,A2:E2,0)),COLUMN(A2:E2)-MIN(COLUMN(A2:E2))+1),1))`

which may require committing with `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER` for your version of Excel.